# Would this question be accepted here?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, specific-question

I am writing a brief paper at university about "state malware". I write that I think there are certain different types (1. Against enemy states e.g. Stuxnet. 2. Against the citizens e.g. surveillance and control).

I am looking for references, background, articles, research and more information about it.

Comment: While the question may not be on-topic, feel free to drop by [the DMZ] - Sec.SE's chat room - and ask around there. It's generally a better place to discuss such open-ended things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, questions asking for resources, links, sources, etc. are off-topic because the answers would just keep growing without end. They are "open-ended" by default.